Why would a local string variable go from "not null" to "maybe null" when assigned to a dictionary?
I have this .NET 8.0 code that uses a Quartz.JobDataMap and gives me weird nullability warnings. I've narrowed it down to this object construction and assignment:
//cronExpression is a non-nullable string parameter
var test1 = cronExpression; //Tooltip says "'cronExpression' is not null here."

// Set up JobDataMap with necessary parameters
var jobDataMap = new JobDataMap
{
   { "JobName", dbJob.JobName },
   { "JobType", dbJob.JobType },
   { "CronExpression", cronExpression },
   { "Id", dbJob.Id }
};
var test2 = cronExpression; //Tooltip says "'cronExpression' may be null here." 

I don't understand how this is possible. What can possibly trick the compiler into thinking this local variable can become null?
And what's the best way to solve it and avoid the spurious nullability warnings down the line?

Can you show a [mre], preferably without depending on other libraries like Quartz?

Please update your post to show the actual types instead of var - otherwise it's hard to know what's going on in your code.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain: No, the compiler normally doesn't make something maybe-null just because you pass it to something that can be null. It does do so if you check whether it's null first. Hopefully with a [mcve] we can look into this in more detail. (And it would only be Nullable<T> if the non-nullable type is a value type.)

I can't reproduce this in Linqpad. (Though my guess is the .Add() method or extension being invoked (behind-the-scenes) by the collection-initializer might be involved?

This won't compile. The JobDataMap declaration is missing the final }. Post real code that actually reproduces the problem. cronExpression isn't reassigned in the question so the compiler shouldn't be fooled. The missing code may be doing something different. We can't guess what JobDataMap is but unless it's a Dictionary, its Add may be causing problems

@PanagiotisKanavos: The compiler can change its view on nullability without reassignment. For example, adding if (cronExpression is null) {} to the code would change the null state to "maybe null" because the compiler things "if the user is explicitly checking, it must be a possibility".

@JonSkeet that's not the case in this code though.

@PanagiotisKanavos that was an editing error, fixed.

@Sweeper Given what I just found out, I'm afraid I won't be able to provide an example that doesn't depend on Quartz, since I think that's where the problem lies.

@PanagiotisKanavos Your comment in the Dictionary Add was spot-on.

Dai thought it first.

@PanagiotisKanavos I merely hinted at the solution

@PanagiotisKanavos: It's true that the code doesn't have that specific statement - but it was just an example of how your reasoning of "cronExpression isn't reassigned in the question so the compiler shouldn't be fooled" is flawed IMO. (That implies that without reassignment, the compiler shouldn't change its view of nullability - and that's not the case.)

I was only talking about this code, and how it didn't make sense unless either code was missing, or JobDataMap wasn't a dictionary. I was still processing Dai's comment while commenting

I think I found the culprit: A bug in Quartz.
JobDataMap's Add method is misdeclared:
public virtual void Add(TKey key, [MaybeNull] TValue value)

MaybeNull was used in place of AllowNull, despite the documentation clearly stating it should be used for inputs, not outputs.

Specifies that an output may be null even if the corresponding type disallows it.

Guess I'll have to see how reporting bugs works...
Edit: Argh, what the decompiler shows and what the actual source code shows are different beasts. Wheras the decompiler showed me a MaybeNull attribute, the current source code simply says public void Add(TKey key, TValue? value) and has apparently been such for five months.
After further inquiry, it appears this bug was fixed in the source code five months ago, but the latest NuGet package I found (v3.13.1 dated 2024-Nov-2) still has it...
As evidenced by the CIL from Quartz.dll v3.13.1:
.method public hidebysig newslot virtual 
        instance void  Add(!TKey key,
                           !TValue 'value') cil managed
{
  .param [2]
  .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNullAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 

Whereas the CIL for a properly declared Add(TKey, TValue?) looks like:
.method public hidebysig instance void  Add(!TKey key,
                                            !TValue 'value') cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 ) 
  .param [2]
  .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = ( 01 00 02 00 00 ) 


Nice catch: so, here we probably have two minor bugs: a warning should be raised for using MaybeNull with non-output parameter and nullability state should not be affected because of usage of the variable for an input parameter (no change happens to the variable).

I agree. There are bugs in Quartz and the C# Roslyn compiler.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes This isn't a bug in Roslyn; Yes, it is normally impossible for a local to be reassigned from null-to-non-null from being used as a non-out/ref call argument but (IIRC) Roslyn raises the warning  because of (for example) libraries using the attribute where new local IL gets inserted during the build-process which could re-set a local to null - or for operator implicit shenanigans.

@Dai Wouldn't the parameter TValue value have to be ref or out?

@OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm unsure of the specifics, but it's mentioned here.
